# Why does mean() have different behavior on empty DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have an empty DataFrame in pandas like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

and I aggregate on groups, the output will **usually** be an empty DataFrame:

```
>>> df.groupby('a', as_index=False).sum()
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

I say **usually** because this is not always the case. It works this way for `min()`, `max()`, `sum()`, `count()`, and `quantile()` but not for `mean()`, that one raises an exception:

```
>>> df.groupby('a', as_index=False).mean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 666, in mean
    return self._cython_agg_general('mean')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2358, in _cython_agg_general
    new_items, new_blocks = self._cython_agg_blocks(how, numeric_only=numeric_only)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2408, in _cython_agg_blocks
    raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
pandas.core.groupby.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Why is the behavior different for this one aggregate function?

I am using pandas 0.14.1 on python 2.7.

Comment: if you look at the source you will see how the different methods are created and called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is raised for the genuine groupby functions: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id35,  when you are calling sum, this is calling the Series or df version which has no such restriction.

So in fact `mean`, `median`, `sem`, `std`, `var` and `ohlc` will all raise an exception.

Note also that if you had non-numerical data, the exception would be raised.

Compare what happens when you call apply with `mean`:

```
In [18]:

df.groupby('a', as_index=False).apply(mean)
Out[18]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

here no exception is raised as the Series or Df version is being applied.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure but I would hypothesize it's because `mean()` would divide by the number of elements in the dataframe, in this case 0.  Which would cause a divide by zero error.  I would just catch the error that is thrown

Comment: I think you're correct, `std()` and `var()` also raise the exception.